# Path to a file without basename

Tags: python

How can I get the path of a file without the file basename?

Something like `/a/path/to/my/file.txt` --> `/a/path/to/my/`

Tried to use `.split('/')` but it's not clean, since you have to add the final `/`, and it's not compatible with all OSes.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Use `os.path.dirname(filename)`.

Answer (score 14):

You can `import os`

```
>>> filepath
'/a/path/to/my/file.txt'
>>> os.path.dirname(filepath)
'/a/path/to/my'
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
(dirname, filename) = os.path.split(path)
```

Comment: more precisely: `(rest, first_path_item) = os.path.split(path)`

Answer (score 5):

Check subs of `os.path`

```
os.path.dirname('/test/one')
```

Answer (score 5):

Since Python 3.4 you can use Pathlib.

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("/a/path/to/my/file.txt")
print(path.parent)
```